# Android countdown timer to time in future

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have an activity that receives two values, one for hour and one for minute. A future time, eg: 21:30

How can I set a countdown timer to run from the current time until the future time that was received ?

here is my timer code, currently set to 30sec for testing

```
    CountDownTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CountDownTextView);

    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             CountDownTextView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             CountDownTextView.setText("Unlocking!");
         }
      }.start();
```

Many thanks

Comment: You can create a calendar object, add the hours / minutes to it and get the Date object for that time in the future. You can then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar targetTime = Calendar.getInstance();
targetTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
targetTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
new CountDownTimer(targetTime.getTimeInMillis()-System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000) {
    // here comes your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First take future timeing then take current timeing calculate difference between it in terms of millisecond then pass this millisecond value as a input to countdown timer class its very easy way to do it